# Page ability to scroll without intention

Tags: html, css

This is a very weird error, but when you load up my page, it can scroll without any intention of it doing so. You can't see the scroll bars, but it just can. I have had issues with this in the past.

```css
html{background-color: rgb(255, 255, 240); max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%; height: 100%; width: 100%;}
body{margin: 0px;}
div#head{display: block; width: 100%; height: 53px; background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); border-radius: 0px;}
div#head > div#icon_logo{display: inline-block; width: 60px; height: 60px; background-image: url("../../Type/Media/Logo_Icon.jpg"); background-size: contain; background-position: center; background-repeat: no-repeat;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML LANG="EN-US">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="description" content="A website for Ty Q." />
    <title>TyPrograms</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Type/Stylesheet/stylesheet_HOME.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="icon" href="Type/Media/Favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="Type/Media/Favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
</head>

<body>
    <div id="head"><div id="icon_logo"></div></div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="CDN/Type/Script/minified/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="CDN/Type/Script/minified/waypoint-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="CDN/Type/Script/minified/angular-1.5.5.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Type/Script/javascript_HOME.js"></script>

</HTML>
```

I honestly don't know what I'm doing wrong, maybe it's the 100% in the width property of the header, I don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set up a fiddle with your code and see nothing wrong.
However, if you dont want your page to scroll you can set `overflow:hidden;` in your css